# 配列から連続して同じものを取り出さない

Tags: perl

配列の要素を一つランダムに抽出しかつ連続して同じものを取り出さないようにするにはどんなテクニックを使えばいいんでしょうか？

ランダムに取り出す部分はできています
大雑把で申し訳ない
教えて下さい

Comment: 前取り出したのを覚えといて、同じの出てきたら再抽選すればえぇんでない？

Comment: 連続しなければ同じものを取り出してもいいんですよね？

Comment: >豚吐露さん 覚えておくという方法が自分には検討がつきません。これは勉強するしかないっすね、、、

Comment: >Yukihiro Hondaさん 自分はforeachかなんかで回したいと考えてるので連続させたいですね。

Comment: コメントどうもです。もう少し調べてみますー

Comment: 質問文内の「連続して同じものを取り出さない」の事です。(1,3,5,6) とあったときに、取り出した結果が、(5,1,5,6,1,3) のように同じものを取り出してもいいのか？(連続して同じものは取り出してない)という確認です

Comment: 一つだけ取り出したいので連続させるのは好ましく無いですね

Answer (score 1):

1) `splice` を使って選んだ要素を削除する。  
2) 選んだ要素を最後の要素と入れ替えて、`pop`(削除)する、あるいは`pop`(削除)せずに選択レンジを１小さくする。

Comment: 早速ありがとうございます！調べてみます！

Comment: これだと「連続して同じ物を取り出さない」ではなく「同じ物を取り出さない(重複無く取り出す)」になると思います。

Comment: @YukihiroHonda  そうですね。要確認だと思いますが、乱数で選択した時に以前選択したものが選択されることがあることが問題であるというように理解しました。

Comment: 技術不足っぽいです、、もう一つ質問させてください
(1,2);
って配列があり
spliceで削除した後popで1小さくしても、結局要素が連続しなかった場合はまた連続してしまいますよね？

この場合はどう対処すれば良いんでしょうか？

Comment: @code00  「結局要素が連続しなかった場合はまた連続してしまいますよね？ 」どういう意味ですか？　取り出した要素がないのだから連続することはないと思いますが・

Comment: ああそっかｗ単純に自分の理解力が残念なだけでした。ありがとうございます。実装してみます

Comment: @code00 1)と2)はどちらかをやればいいです。1)のあとに2)をやるってことではないですよ。

Comment: @Yukihiro Honda はい